# Why won't this DIV hide using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `div` - I need to hide this `div` if a `td` on the same page contains some text.

In this case - if the `td` says "Shipping" - I want the `div` to be hidden. It doesn't seem to work.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8X88/5/)

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  if ('#TBL1 table tr').has('td:contains("Shipping")') {
    $("#myDiv").hide();
  } else {
    // code to be executed if condition is false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TBL1" class="ShipEst">
  <table align="right" style="width: 100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">
          <b>Subtotal: </b>
        </td>
        <td align="center"></td>
        <td align="right">
          <nobr>25.00</nobr>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">
          <b>Shipping: </b>
        </td>
        <td align="center"></td>
        <td align="right">
          <nobr>0.00</nobr>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
  Hide this if td contains "Shipping"
</div>
```

I'm trying to do this with jQuery. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if ( $('#TBL1 table tr td:contains("Shipping")').length )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Vohuman said you need `.length` to read the property, otherwise it will always return true.

And the issue for start was the missing `$` in your `if` statement

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#TBL1 table tr td').has(':contains("Shipping")').length) {
    $("#myDiv").hide();
  } else {
    // code to be executed if condition is false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TBL1" class="ShipEst">
  <table align="right" style="width: 100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">
          <b>Subtotal: </b>
        </td>
        <td align="center"></td>
        <td align="right">
          <nobr>25.00</nobr>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">
          <b>Shipping: </b>
        </td>
        <td align="center"></td>
        <td align="right">
          <nobr>0.00</nobr>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
  Hide this if td contains "Shipping"
</div>
```

Comment: So just using the `contains()` without `has` won't work why?, because AFAIK it is doing what OP wants. it is "filtering" for `td` s that containing that string, and when returning true does hide the other div that OP wants. What is wrong ?

Comment: @Vohuman Thanks, I've updated the answer, since I noticed the answer was incorrect and voted yours up.

Comment: This is actually what worked best for me. Thanks again everyone for all your input.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. Syntax errors. The syntax of the `if` statement should be:

   ```
   if ( $('#TBL1 table tr').has('td:contains("Shipping")') ) {
   ```
2. `.has` returns a *filtered* jQuery object. An object is always a truthy value in JavaScript, even for jQuery collections that have no elements. You need to read the `.length` property of the returned collection:

   ```
   if ( $('#TBL1 table tr').has('td:contains("Shipping")').length ) {
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to select #TBL1 as JQuery selector. Do this:

```
if($('#TBL1 table tr').has('td:contains("Shipping")')){
$("#myDiv").hide();
}
else {
// code to be executed if condition is false
```

}